# Application of tidy-data principles to biological data

Tags: r, dataset

I have been reading up on [tidy-data concept](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) and the tidyr package, as well as some tutorials. I started to think how I would go about applying those principles to my real world data and got a bit stuck.

As things stand I have a tabular file, containing measurements of peptides over a number of samples, that is approx 20000 x 66 large (this is essentially a trimmed version already). The structure is as follows:

```
Observations: 19,576
Variables: 66
$ Cluster ID       (chr) "1478878045944", "1478878294868", "1478878406996", "147887...
$ Peptide Sequence (chr) "AAAAKPNNLSLVVHGPGDLR 42.0105647@A1", "AAAANLCPGDVILAIDGFG...
$ External IDs     (chr) "NX_Q00796-2,NX_Q00796-1", "NX_Q53GG5-2,NX_Q53GG5-1,NX_Q53...
$ Charge           (int) 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2...
$ Average RT       (dbl) 65.61118, 99.66750, 105.79376, 43.88064, 49.66660, 38.1385...
$ Average m/z      (dbl) 681.3753, 1068.4971, 1063.1664, 745.8591, 832.4116, 503.27...
$ N33              (dbl) 10941400, NA, NA, 21923600, NA, 8519010, 6439150, 8220830,...
$ T38              (dbl) 10589700, NA, NA, 26150600, NA, 16326000, 10410400, 170873...
...
```

As you can see, the first 6 columns are meta data about the peptides, while the following 60 columns contain the values across the samples (i.e. individuals).

My understanding is that this structure isn't tidy, since each sample should be an observation and each peptide should be a variable. But it's not as simple as transposing the data frame (or data.table), since the first 6 columns need to be modified as well.

If I understand this right, in order to be "tidy" each row should contain the observations (or samples), 60 in total, and some 19000+ columns representing each variable, plus some other meta data e.g. sample type (T/N).

Wouldn't this cause an extremely wide table, it would make it very difficult to view the data. Also I don't think I'll even need to be able to index the table based on Peptide Sequence for example..

Have I misunderstood something? How should I tidy or organize my data, before going into the analysis stage? The goal for the analysis is to join this table with another table which contains clinical data, including survival times and try to find important variables with respect to survival analysis.

Comment: What do these 19,576 observations represent? And what would be the advantage for your analysis if you make them columns?

Comment: @Tahir they are the analytes I mentioned in the question, we have measured about 20,000 analytes over 60 samples (with NAs of course).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what an analyte is, and in the dictionary it is defined as "a substance whose chemical constituents are being identified and measured." But that is not helpful, why do you want to make these analytes columns? And again, what would be the advantage for your analysis if you make them columns?

Comment: They are some molecules we measure, abundances of which are interesting. I am not trying to make them anything, just trying to "tidy" up my data according to the good practices that are out there

Comment: I see, let me ask in this way: let's say you make them columns, so your first column will be analyte 1,  second analyte 2, etc. Rows will be their values across samples. But then what are you going to do with those values? For example, are you going to do some analyses on the difference between these two analytes across samples (rows here)? So, I think your interest is much more important here.

Comment: Tahir is right, and in your post you already mention it; first you need to decide which analysis you would like to do. E.g. *expression* or *cgh* data come with their own classes for which methods are available. If you want to apply some other analysis you can think of making data tidy. In that case using `methods(class(data))` will list available methods which you can use to extract untidy data and then make them tidy.

Comment: btw you are wrong about transposing it. You have 60 varaibles (that are you columns in tidy format) and you have your 19k observations (which are samples in tidy format)

Comment: @Drey I have edited the question to give a better description of the problem and goals of the study.

Comment: "The goal for the analysis is to join this table" [with clinical information] -> then yes, it may be worth it. But you need to be careful and you must master some data processing aspects (i don't know how familiar you are). You your need this only once than don't bother with tidy format. If you will need the concepts on regular basis in your projects than after a lot of practice many things will become more or less easy. It is up to you. If you post some publicly available data (link?) maybe someone will post some code. Also see BioStars.org for biological expertise.